# Changing object value with onClick event

Tags: javascript, object, onclick

Sorry to ask this again, but I wanted to add more code for context.

I am making a rock paper scissors game and want to change the playerChoice key when a button the button is pressed.

I want to add an onclick event to each button and run a function that will set the playerChoice property so it references the gameOptions index.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Lapis, Papyrus Scalpellus</h1>

<h2>Make a Choice</h2>
<button id="Lapis">Lapis</button>
<button id="Papyrus">Papyrus</button>
<button id=Scalpellus>Scalpellus</button>
<h2>Game Results</h2>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>


const gameOptions = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

const newChoice = randomChoice();

console.log(newChoice);

const humanPlayer = {
  playerChoice: gameOptions[0],
};

const computerPlayer = {
  playerChoice: randomChoice(),
};

document.querySelector("#Lapis").onclick = function() {
  humanPlayer.playerChoice = gameOptions[0];
};

document.querySelector("#Papyrus").onclick = function() {
  humanPlayer.playerChoice = gameOptions[1];
};
document.querySelector("#Scalpellus").onclick = function() {
  humanPlayer.playerChoice = gameOptions[2];
};

console.log(humanPlayer);

//Random Choice
function randomChoice() {
  const theChoice = gameOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
  return theChoice;
}

//Players 

function resultText(innerText){
  const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
  paragraph.innerText = innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
}


//Outcomes
function fight(){
  if(computerPlayer.playerChoice === humanPlayer.playerChoice){
     resultText("Its a Tie!20. You chose " + humanPlayer.playerChoice + " and the computer chose " + computerPlayer.playerChoice);
  }else if (computerPlayer.playerChoice === "Lapis"){
    if(humanPlayer.playerChoice === "Papyrus"){
     resultText("Human Player Wins!6. You chose " + humanPlayer.playerChoice + " and the computer chose " + computerPlayer.playerChoice);
    }else if( humanPlayer.playerChoice === "Scalpellus"){
       resultText("Computer Player Wins!5 You chose " + humanPlayer.playerChoice + " and the computer chose " + computerPlayer.playerChoice);

    }
  }else if(computerPlayer.playerChoice === "Papyrus"){
    if ( humanPlayer.playerChoice === "Lapis"){
      resultText("Compter Player Wins!4. You chose " + humanPlayer.playerChoice + " and the computer chose " + computerPlayer.playerChoice);

    }else if( humanPlayer.playerChoice === "Scalpellus"){
      resultText("Human Player Wins!3. You chose " + humanPlayer.playerChoice + " and the computer chose " + computerPlayer.playerChoice);

    }
  }else if(computerPlayer.playerChoice === "Scalpellus"){
    if ( humanPlayer.playerChoice === "Lapis"){
      resultText("Human Player Wins!2. You chose " + humanPlayer.playerChoice + " and the computer chose " + computerPlayer.playerChoice);

    }else if( humanPlayer.playerChoice === "Papyrus"){
      resultText("Computer Player Wins!1. You chose " + humanPlayer.playerChoice + " and the computer chose " + computerPlayer.playerChoice);
    }
  }
}

fight()
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? You say "I want to add an onclick event to each button and run a function that will set the playerChoice property so it references the gameOptions index." and you do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to keep your code simple:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", btnHandler);
}
```

And then your handler function will be called each time a button is clicked without the need to repeat your code:

```
function btnHandler(el){
  switch (el.getAttribute("id")){
    case "Papyrus":
    ...
    default: break;
  }
}
```

It also allows you to pass the button element itself, so you can just pull out the ID attribute when needed, rather than having to pass a parameter for each different instance across separate calls. For the win condition check, you can eliminate several "if" statements by simply seeing if they're equal, and if they're not, only compare the human choice to the computer choice which would beat it and set the result thusly. It can be optimized further, but I imagine you would like to learn something from this so I've commented the fiddle as well.

For this example, I also moved the fight() function to the button handler so the player would have a choice, and the computer's choice would only be triggered at that point as well. There were a few instances in your original code which called functions and set variables, but didn't use them etc, as well as a few syntax errors.

See attached fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s0toz3L8/2/